# Using a Tumblr API in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, api, rubygems, tumblr

I am using `tumblr_client` gem to access Tumblr API.

I want to search all users posts containing a certain tag, not search a certain users posts containing a certain tag. I do not see documentation within the [tumblr_client](https://rubygems.org/gems/tumblr_client) gem to be able to do this so I guessed the code and left the user link blank.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'cinch'
require 'tumblr_client'

client = Tumblr::Client.new({
  :consumer_key => '[redacted]',
  :consumer_secret => '[redacted]',
  :oauth_token => '[redacted]',
  :oauth_token_secret => '[redacted]'
})

# Make the request
client.info

p client.posts('', :tag => "pony", :type => "photo", :limit => 10)
```

This is the current code that I am using, expecting 10 photos of a pony, but instead it results in this error message.

```
{"status"=>404, "msg"=>"Not Found"}
```

Please assist?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `posts` endpoint for this. If you look at [the code](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr_client/blob/v0.8.5/lib/tumblr/blog.rb#L33), it's generating a URL (via [`blog_path`](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr_client/blob/v0.8.5/lib/tumblr/helpers.rb#L6-L8)) that uses the blog name you must provide in the first argument:

```
def blog_path(blog_name, ext)
  "v2/blog/#{full_blog_name(blog_name)}/#{ext}"
end
```

If you don't include `blog_name`, the URL is `v2/blog//posts`, and now it's obvious why you get a 404.

You want to be using the [tagged](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr_client/blob/v0.8.5/lib/tumblr/tagged.rb#L4) endpoint, like so:

```
client.tagged('cool_things')
```